# How can i make my textview in center of a layout that is added dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

The following is my layout code. I have to add a TextView dynamically in my Java code to the FrameLayout with id "lay_content". My requirement is to center the TextView in this layout. I tried a lot using properties like gravity and centerInParent but I am unable to make it appear in center. Please help me out. Thanks in advance!

```
<CustomLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/window_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_black_selector"
            android:text="@string/close_x"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/lay_title"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/divider"
        android:layout_margin="10dip">
    </FrameLayout>    
</CustomLayout>
```

Comment: Get the screen width and height. Then set the top and left margin accordingly. Set the text of the textview to ""(Clear) and then dynamically add text from java saying TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lay_content);  t1.setText(TEXT);

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Layout params on the text view while adding it in a frame layout. Below is the sample code for that.-

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);   layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

FrameLayout framlayout = (FrameLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lay_content);
framlayout.addView(textView);
```

Hope it helps. :)